# How to evaluate the following total integral?

Tags: integration

I am not getting how to simplify the total differential:  $ d\Big(\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(t)dt\Big).$ Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A cursory look at the fundamental theorem of calculus, and how it can be applied here, will be helpful to you.

Comment: I couldn't understand. Can you make it clear

Comment: You must have done the fundamental theorem of calculus. Edit the question above, and state the version of the fundamental theorem of calculus that you know, or that has been taught to you. I think that this problem is an application of the FTC, but I want to ensure that I proceed using what you know rather than what I know, hence my request.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What makes sense is $g(\lambda) = \int_{a(\lambda)}^{b(\lambda)} f(\lambda,t)dt$, $g'(\lambda) = f(\lambda,b(\lambda))b'(\lambda)-f(\lambda,a(\lambda))a'(\lambda)+\int_{a(\lambda)}^{b(\lambda)} \frac{\partial f(\lambda,t)}{\partial \lambda}dt$

Answer (score 0):

I think it should read $\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(x)dx$.

I suppose that $f$ is a continuous function defined on an intevall $I$ and that $a$ and $b$ are differentiable on $I$.

Let $c \in I$ and define  $F(t):= \int_{c}^{t}f(x)dx$. By the Fundamental theorem, $F$ is differentiable and $F'=f$ on $I$.

We then have $$\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(x)dx=F(b(t))-F(a(t)).$$

Now use the chain rule.